# Passing injected dependencies to external functions

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, design-patterns, dependency-injection, nestjs

I have a NestJS application where I have some logic in regards to using AWS S3 buckets.

I have one module, which contains a service with a `promiseWrapper` function, to convert callback to async.

```js
  private s3PromiseWrapper(action: string, params: S3ParamGetDTO): Promise<string> {
    console.log(params)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.s3.getSignedUrl(
        action,
        {
          Bucket: params.bucketName,
          Key: params.key,
          Expires: params.expirationTimeSeconds,
        },
        (err: any, url: string) => {
          if (err) reject(err)
          resolve(url)
        }
      )
    })
```

No have another module, that needs to use the same function, so to not repeat the code I wanted to create a global function as a `util` function, but this requires me to pass the instance as an argument to the function.

```js
  private s3PromiseWrapper(action: string, params: S3ParamGetDTO, s3Instance: S3): Promise<string> {
    console.log(params)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      s3Instance.getSignedUrl(
        action,
        {
          Bucket: params.bucketName,
          Key: params.key,
          Expires: params.expirationTimeSeconds,
        },
        (err: any, url: string) => {
          if (err) reject(err)
          resolve(url)
        }
      )
    })
```

Is this anti-pattern in terms of dependency injection?

Comment: Why not just use the `S3.getSignedUrlPromise` method instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an s3 wrapper as following

```
 @Injectable({scope: transient})
    export class S3Service {

    private s3 = null //or just initiate the object;

    init() {
      this.s3 = new S3();
    }

    s3PromiseWrapper(action: string, params: S3ParamGetDTO): Promise<string> {
        console.log(params)
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.s3.getSignedUrl(
            action,
            {
              Bucket: params.bucketName,
              Key: params.key,
              Expires: params.expirationTimeSeconds,
            },
            (err: any, url: string) => {
              if (err) reject(err)
              resolve(url)
            }
          )
        })
    }
```

Inject the same service in any other service

```
MYService() {
  constructor(
    private s3: S3Service
  ) {
    this.s3.init()
  }

  mymethod() {
    this.s3.s3PromiseWrapper()
  }
}
```

**However, do write a wrapper for something else required.**

javascript aws-sdk already provides the promisied version of all methods.
which can be accessed by appending `.promise()` to methods.

for example

```
this.s3.getSignedUrl(params).promise()
```